# php artisan serve not respond of next url

Tags: laravel-5

I use laravel 5.6.34. I installed Laravel with the clone github laravel / laravel and `composer install`. I make a route something like this

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::prefix('admin')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', function () {
        echo 'Hello Admin';
    });
});
```

I run `php artisan serve` it work fine in first url `localhost:8000`, but when I try to open second url `localhost:8000/admin` it keep loading. Because I can't wait I stop `php artisan serve` with `ctrl + c`, but the strange thing happens when I run `exit` cmd not closed. Can anyone tell what's wrong? And sorry for bad english.

Comment: can you try  localhost:8000/index.php/admin

Answer (score 0):

```
<Directory /var/www/html/sites/test/public>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

add this rule in virtualhost basically AllowOverride All*

check is a2enmod rewrite enabled  or not and 
check .htaccess file

more info check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869092/how-to-enable-mod-rewrite-for-apache-2-2)

Answer (score 0):

after I did research, I knew the main problem. There no problem in code. The problem come from avast antivirus that try block artisan console. so to fix this problem just disable your avast anti virus when development stage.

Comment: Nice you figured it out :)